# Scikit-Learn - Error importing custom Cython files

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cython

I want to create custom `Splitter` and `DecisionTreeRegressor` classes to be used with `RandomForestRegressor` in sklearn.  However, the `Splitter` class is written in Cython.  The sklearn GitHub repo has two splitter files, one `pxd` and one `pyd`: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/fd237278e895b42abe8d8d09105cbb82dc2cbba7/sklearn/tree

What I've read about Cython indicates that there is a manual compilation step required to use Cython code, but I would think (or hope) that I could just manually edit the `_splitter.pxd` and `_splitter.pyd` files since that's how they are laid out in the GitHub repo and I'm obviously not compiling anything when I use sklearn.  However, I get a couple of errors when trying to do this on macOS.

Using the Spyder IDE, I get an invalid syntax error from this line in `_splitter.pxd` when I try to make a copy of that file and import my copied version rather than the sklearn version:

```
cimport numpy as np
```

Again, this line is identical to the `cimport` statement in `_splitter.pxd` in sklearn:  https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e895b42abe8d8d09105cbb82dc2cbba7/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pxd

Also, when trying to import the splitter file by mirroring the import in sklearn, I get a `No module named...` error:

```
import sklearn_custom.tree._splitter
```

I double checked that this is not just an issue with Spyder by running it on the command line and still got the error.

So I'm wondering what python/sklearn are doing behind the scenes that allow the Cython code to run as is and without compilation or any of the Cython-specific imports that are found in the Cython instructions (https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html).  Is compiling unavoidable if I want to write custom Cython to be used with sklearn?  If so, what exactly do I do with the existing `pyx` and `pxd` files (mainly the latter since there's no mention of `pxd` in the Cython instructions and the `pxd` file is not imported into the `pyx` file) that already exist for sklearn?